# Spring Boot Yaml property placeholder escape character in VS Code vs IntelliJ behavior not consistent

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code, properties, yaml, placeholder

I have the following problem with property placed holders in Spring Boot v2.3.12.RELEASE. My team uses both VS Code and IntelliJ to develop and we're running into this interesting behavior with property placeholders. In IntelliJ, we escape the `${}` notation using `\`, i.e. `\${}`. In VS Code, `\${}` does not work for us.

**Here's what our property looks like in `application.yml`**

`kafka://\${spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers}/\${output-topic}`

If we remove `\` then this will work in VS Code, but fail in IntelliJ. So we're in a bit of a conundrum. Is there a solution for this that we can't see? Thank you.

**How these properties are using in our Spring Boot app:**

- We bind our `application.yml` properties to Java Beans using `@ConfigurationProperties`

**How we run our app in VS Code:**

- We use VS Code launch configurations to start our apps
- We are not using environment variables. Everything is maintained within the `application-{env}.yml` files
- If we keep the escaping `\` character, I can see that my placeholders are evaluated, but then we get the following error:

```
Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'some.properties' to com.project.config.prop.ProjectProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13a2c436 failed:

    Property: video-pipeline.ocr-service.kafka-properties.destinationUri
    Value: kafka://\localhost:9092/\some_topic
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:196:30
    Reason:
```

- To make this work for VS Code, we must remove the `\` character; however, this then breaks the application from starting in IntelliJ

**How we run our app in IntelliJ:**

- We run the application using IntelliJ run configurations for Spring Boot
- We are not using environment variables. The placeholders in our application.yml file, i.e. `\${spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-server}` and `\${output-topic}` are configured in environment specific yaml files, e.g. `application-dev.yml, application-stage.yml, application-prod.yml`
- In IntelliJ, if we remove the escaping `\` character (to make our VS Code use case work), then we get the following error when we try to launch our application:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processResources'.
> Could not copy file '/path/to/app/src/main/resources/application.yml' to '/path/to/app/build/resources/main/application.yml'.
   > Missing property (spring) for Groovy template expansion. Defined keys [parent, classLoaderScope, dependencyMetaDataProvider, configurations, plugins, objects, logger, rootDir, path, testResultsDirName, targetCompatibility, java, artifactoryPassword, normalization, bootJar, childProjects, jar, model, state, processResources, serviceRegistryFactory, tasks, ext, projectDir, dependencyLocking, projectEvaluationBroadcaster, dependencyManagement, projectPath, testing, inheritedScope, version, script, dependencies, extensions, modelRegistry, projectEvaluator, projectConfigurator, archivesBaseName, logging, configurationActions, sourceCompatibility, status, subprojects, components, displayName, javaToolchains, parentIdentifier, antBuilderFactory, standardOutputCapture, docsDir, defaultTasks, crossProjectModelAccess, buildScriptSource, autoTargetJvmDisabled, reportsDir, baseClassLoaderScope, services, gradle, taskThatOwnsThisObject, distsDirName, buildFile, compileIntTestJava, depth, docsDirName, scmVersion, modelIdentityDisplayName, testResultsDir, buildDir, scriptHandlerFactory, deferredProjectConfiguration, project, repositories, scriptPluginFactory, testReportDir, checkstyle, group, artifacts, test, configurationTargetIdentifier, compileJava, fileResolver, internalStatus, name, testReportDirName, buildscript, springBoot, distsDirectory, libsDirectory, processOperations, asDynamicObject, publicType, classes, identityPath, description, sourceSets, buildPath, fileOperations, pluginManager, defaultArtifacts, detachedState, class, reporting, convention, owner, allprojects, pluginContext, ant, resources, clean, compileTestJava, rootScript, layout, artifactoryUsername, listenerBuildOperationDecorator, integrationTest, rootProject, libsDirName, properties, providers, base].
```

**We've tried the following:**

- Surrounding our property in single and double quotes
- Removing the escaping `\` character, but this just ends up breaking our application in IntelliJ
- I couldn't find a solution online or any related issues in both the Sprint Boot project and Spring Boot Tools project for VS Code

The only semi-related documentation I could find is provided here in the main Spring Boot repo:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/c0c67f2593dbfd17aa304b43f4da3a3678fa58eb

Comment: It's interesting. Only ${env_variable_name} is correct YAML syntax for placeholders. Where exactly are you using this on IntelliJ?

Comment: Hi @Mar-Z, there's nothing special I think with our IntelliJ setup. We're using these placeholders in our base application.yml file and the expressions, e.g. `${spring.boot.kafka.producer}` are set in environment specific property files. Our application file structure is what gradle configures by default. Please let me know if this helps answer your question :)

Comment: Please be more specific and add to the question: how are you running the app? How are you setting the env variables? What error are you getting? For IntelliJ only because it looks like VSC works correct.

Comment: @Mar-Z thanks for pointing out the confusion. I've updated the question with more details and I've clarified which errors are observed where. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using environment variables but the environment specific property files you can get rid of the placeholders and override the properties instead.

For example in application.yml:

```
destinationUri: kafka://kafkaserver:9092/some_topic
```

in application-dev.yml:

```
destinationUri: kafka://localhost:9092/some_topic
```